# I deployed a Meteor site about a week about and told no one. Google Analytics says I have 312 users & 345 sessions. Why?

Tags: meteor, google-analytics

I'm very new to online analytics. I just deployed a site a few days ago, told no one, and Google Analytics is saying I have hundreds of users and sessions all over the world.

Even if events are logging from my own development, there shouldn't be so many users (and so many sessions...I'm not developing THAT vigorously.)

Also, my server logs indicate the level of activity I expect: ~0. So it's not like I'm magically getting traffic somehow. It really is nonexistent.

What could be going on? I can understand seeing a few sessions here and there, for web crawlers, but I don't understand why the numbers are so high.

Any common gotchas?

I realize this is a vague question, but I'm not sure what other information to provide, so please let me know what I can do to help.

Answer (score 2):

### Traffic source

First check, if traffic comes through your website (through your analytics.js library). To do this, just remove analytics.js for a while and check, if traffic is still going into Google Analytics (e.g. Realtime report).

If is still going, maybe somebody use Measurement Protocol to spam your account.

To prevent this, add, for instance, custom parameter into your call and create filtered view only for this. All without this param, throw away.

### Check sessions and returning visitors

Check, if the traffic is random (usualy one pageview per session) or if the behavior of users is normal.

### Custom client ID

Check if you dont play with client ID in analytics.js configuration. IF you dont have random number generator there.

### Check traffic source (referal), browsers

If there is one significant, or there is some pattern in versioning (absolute randomness is pattern too)

### Preventing random access through website

For every visitor who is first-time on your page, set up a cookie with current timestamp. If cookie is not older than e.g. hour or day, do not track this user. Or buffer hits and fire them later after you prove the user is real.

---

Anyway, if you have some new hints or information from your analysis, we should help you better. This is still like reading a magic sphere :-)